# Initating an Array inside a Class

Tags: php, arrays, class, subclass

I have been having a hella of a time trying to get an array to initialize inside a class.  What I am trying to attempt is to create a side menu using an array and a child class.  I have tried to solve this problem for several days and now I'm asking for help.  I have a feeling I am missing something basic as I am just learning PHP.

Below is my code and the commented out lines are attempts at a solution that have not worked.

```
<?php
/*************   global  variables  ******************************/
 //global $house_array, $car_array, $vacation_array, $company_address;
$company_name = "Heaven HVAC";
$street = '12345 Blue Canyon Rd.'; 
$company_citystatezip = "Heaven, CA 91777";

/*************   end global  variables  **************************/

 echo '<H1 align="center">Calling Array inside Child Class</H1>';


 class Company{
 //// insert object variables (properties) HERE
 var $company_url = "http://localhost";
 var $company_email = "example@example.com ";

 //// insert methods here
  function getHeader($company_name, $color) {
    $topheader = "<TABLE align='center'; style='background-color:$color; width:50%'><TR><TD>";
    $topheader .= "<H1 style='text-align:center'>$company_name</H1>";
    $topheader .= "</TD></TR></TABLE>";
    return $topheader;                                      
 }

  function getFooter($color) {
  $this->address;
   $bottomfooter = "<TABLE align='center'; style='background-color:$color;width:50%'><TR><TD>";
  $bottomfooter .= "<center><b><u>$this->address</center></b></u>";
  $bottomfooter .= "</TD></TR></TABLE>";
   return $bottomfooter;
   }
 }  // end class Company

  //// Working On child class - If commented out, then the code has been tried and failed
 class AirCondition extends Company {
 var $navbar_array;

 //// create array
 function  create_navbar_array ( )  {
 $mainurl = $this->company_url;
 $this->navbar_array = array( "Home Page"=>"$mainurl?whichpage=home", "Sales"=>"$mainurl?whichpage=sales",
   "Support" => "$mainurl?whichpage=support", "Contacts" => "$mainurl?whichpage=contact" );
 }

 //create_navbar_array();
 // return $navbar_array;

  function getLeftNavBar($array){

  //    create_navbar_array();

  ## Create a table to display arrays
  print "<TABLE BORDER='1'>";
  echo '<tr><td>Navigation Menu</td></tr>'; 
        foreach($array as $Page){                       
            echo "<tr><td>{$Page}</td></tr>";
            return $array;
            }                   
  echo "</TABLE>";
  }
 }


 $HVACcompany = new AirCondition();
 $HVACcompany->address = "777 Estate Rd <br /> $company_citystatezip";
 echo $HVACcompany->getHeader($company_name, orange);
 echo "<br/>";
 echo $HVACcompany->getFooter(green);

 //echo $HVACcompany->getLeftNavBar();
 //echo $HVACcompnay->create_navbar_array();
 //$HVACcompnay->create_navbar_array();
 $HVACcompany->getLeftNavBar($navbar_array);

 ?>
```

I am able to create the web page layout, but the array isn't initializing.  What am I doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line:

```
$HVACcompany->getLeftNavBar($navbar_array);
```

should be:

```
$HVACcompany->getLeftNavBar($HVACcompany->navbar_array);
```

Because $navbar_array was never declared in the global namespace, however it was declared as a public variable within the class AirCondition which was initialized with the variable $HVACcompany.

Additionally you need to call the function `$HVACcompany->create_navbar_array();`
before calling `$HVACcompany->getLeftNavBar($HVACcompany->navbar_array);` in order to create the array $navbar_array.

Also remove the `return $array;` statement inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I tried the change and the array still isn't being outputted, just the table.  Is there something wrong with the foreach loop?

Comment: @JDean You never executed the function `$HVACcompany->create_navbar_array();` in order to create the array $navbar_array.

Comment: Ok, I did that, and it's now only outputting the first element in the array, the "home" element.  Why isn't the entire array outputting?

Comment: remove `return $array;` inside the foreach loop. By using the return statement, it stops the loop.

Comment: That was it...Thank you